# How to fix Ubuntu Forbidden issue on localhost?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, lamp

I have installed Lamp and phpmyadmin in Ubuntu running on my computer.  This is my `Ls- L` result on terminal.

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root     4096 Jul  3 12:30 backups
drwxr-xr-x 19 root    root     4096 Jul  3 13:37 cache
drwxrwsrwt  2 root    whoopsie 4096 Jul  3 12:30 crash
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root     4096 Feb 14 03:55 games
drwxr-xr-x 61 root    root     4096 Jul  3 13:37 lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root    staff    4096 Apr 19  2012 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root        9 Jul  3 15:50 lock -> /run/lock
drwxr-xr-x 18 root    root     4096 Jul  3 16:56 log
drwxrwsr-x  2 root    mail     4096 Feb 14 03:52 mail
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root     4096 Feb 14 03:52 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root        4 Jul  3 15:50 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x  8 root    root     4096 Feb 14 03:53 spool
drwxrwxrwt  2 root    root     4096 Jul  3 17:16 tmp
drwxr-x--x  3 krishna root     4096 Jul  3 15:11 www
```

When I enter `http://localhost/` in the browser, it says

**Forbidden**

You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80.
I am able to create files and folders in var/www folder but I'm unable to execute it from the browser.
How to fix this issue, please, suggest me? I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: What's in your `www` folder?

Comment: i have a folder furniture and default index.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `/var/www` folder needs to be readable by the `www-data` system account. Try this :

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

**Edit** : as noted by Joachim Isaksson, that was a quick fix to the problem. A more secure way of setting up the permissions would look like :

```
sudo chown -R krishna:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

You might need to give write access to `www-data` at some point though, for example to enable file uploads to your server. It's best if you can keep this to a dedicated directory in your website tree.

Comment: `chmod -R 755 /var/www` should be enough.

Comment: it says 
`krishna@krishna:/var$ sudo chown -R www:root /var/www
[sudo] password for krishna: 
chown: invalid user: `www:root'
krishna@krishna:/var$ `

Comment: Yes, my mistake, it's actually www-data on Ubuntu.

Comment: Good thing that it solved the problem. That said, I think www-data should probably not be owner of the directory with 755 permissions, that means the web server can write to the web root and replace all your scripts. To me, having someone else own the directory and giving group _read_ permission for the _group_ www-data feels safer.